# Save object in binary to file, how to serialize correctly?

Tags: java, scala, serialization

I am working on a small voxel-engine right now and I'm at the point where I need to write some parts of the world from the cache to the filesystem.

Now I am kind of baffled... I have this:

```
@SerialVersionUID(1L)
class Chunk(val position: Vector3) extends Externalizable
{
  val blocks = Array.ofDim[Short](WIDTH, HEIGHT, DEPTH)
  private val mesh = new ChunkMesh(this)    

  override def readExternal(in: ObjectInput): Unit =
  {
    val x = in.readInt
    val y = in.readInt
    val z = in.readInt

    position.set(x,y,z)

    for
    {
      a <- 0 until blocks(0).length
      b <- 0 until blocks(1).length
      c <- 0 until blocks(2).length
    }
    {
      if(in.available() > 0) blocks(a)(b)(c) = in.readShort()
    }
  }

  override def writeExternal(out: ObjectOutput): Unit =
  {
    out.writeInt(position.x.toInt)
    out.writeInt(position.y.toInt)
    out.writeInt(position.z.toInt)

    for
    {
      a <- 0 until blocks(0).length
      b <- 0 until blocks(1).length
      c <- 0 until blocks(2).length
    }
      out.writeShort(blocks(a)(b)(c))
  }
}
```

Now according to this: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch12s08.html this would be enough.

But alas, I thought so from the beginning:

> java.io.InvalidClassException: world.Chunk; no valid constructor

so, adding a default constructor...

```
class Chunk extends Externalizable
{
  var position: Vector3 = new Vector3(0,0,0)

  def this(position: Vector3) =
  {
    this()
    this.position = position
  }
  //...
}
```

position is initialized to avoid `NullPointerEexceptions` in `readExternal`. It's also a var, so it can be set upon instantiation.

Now I still get nullpointers on `mesh` but what I get most of the time is:

> java.io.EOFException

during `readExternal`

Please point me to some kind of tutorial about serialization... all I find is doing it as I do, or even easier. I deliberately chose to extend `Externizable` as to be able to define exactly what should be written to binary and what not.

The last time I serialized something by hand has been a few years and never in Scala.

Comment: It looks like it should work to me. You may want to consider using [SCodec](https://github.com/scodec/scodec#introduction) as an alternative to `Externalizable`, to remove the need for `var` and get better error messages.

Comment: One possibility I can think of is that you aren't flushing/closing the stream you are writing to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you don't have a public no-arguments constructor.

Comment: Yes, I do. In scala the default-constructor is the one you provide in the class-declaration itself, so the default-constructor is `class Chunk() extends Externizable` That's why I defined another constructor with an argument down there. Have a look at http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-multiple-class-constructors-in-scala-alternate-constructors